# Why is this exception occurring：Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)

Tags: spring-webflux, project, reactive

I am learning Reactive, but I encountered some issues. I used WebClient and then subscribed, but encountered the exception Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)

I don't know how to do it

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("Hello, Reactor!");

        mono.subscribe(
                result -> System.out.println("Result: " + result),
                error -> System.err.println("Error: " + error),
                () -> System.out.println("Operation completed")
        );

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://api.google.com");

        Mono<String> resultMono = webClient.get()
                .uri("/endpoint")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .map(response -> {
                    System.out.println("Mapping in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    return response;
                });

        resultMono.subscribe(System.out::println);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is difficult to know how to solve this. The posted code does not seem to reproduce the error (It raises a 404, which is expected because the endpoint does not exist). If I replace the url with just 'https://www.google.com/', and duplicate the `resultMono.subscribe(System.out::println)` line, I do not see any error. The request is well triggered twice, and the html page is printed twice in my console. Can you provide a real minimal reproducer of your problem please ? Note that some Mono might only be triggered once (for example, if it has been created from a wrapped java.util.Stream).

Comment: [main] DEBUG reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Duplicate Subscription has been detected
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Spec. Rule 2.12 - Subscriber.onSubscribe MUST NOT be called more than once (based on object equality)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'reactor.util.context.ContextView reactor.core.publisher.MonoSink.contextView()'